# replace all images with inputs elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need find all images from textarea value and then replaces with inputs text elements
and the value of those  with the src of the img was reemplace

after that the final string is output on a new div ('#newDiv')

my script dont replace nothing i dont know why

here is what i have done so far,

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<textarea id="caja"></textarea>

<input type="button" onClick="parsingHtml()" value="read">


<div id="newDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

function parsingHtml()
{

  var content = $('#caja').val();
  var newContent = $(content).find("img").replaceWith('<input type="text">');

  alert(newContent)
  $('#newDiv').html(newContent);
};
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: Not clear. Show the relevant part of your HTML.

Comment: Try this: `$('#caja').find("img")....` avoiding `content` altogether

Comment: thanks @Lokesh, already done that not luck =/

Comment: @PM77-1 i add all the code from my document, thanks!

Comment: ***dont replace nothing*** means *replace something*?

Comment: are textarea contains images?

Comment: yes textarea contain html , from user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems that I can see

1. `newContent` is referring to only the `img` elements, not the complete content
2. Since you are passing the value to `jQuery`, if the value does not start with `<` it will be considered as a selector not as a element creation command

So

```js
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($) {
  //click event handler registration
  $('#read').click(parsingHtml);
})

function parsingHtml() {
  var content = $('#caja').val();
  var newContent = $('<div />', {
    html: content
  });
  newContent.find("img").replaceWith('<input type="text">');

  console.log(newContent)
  $('#newDiv').html(newContent.contents());

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="caja"></textarea>

<input type="button" id="read" value="read">


<div id="newDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Arun P Johny, thanks that is correct, thanks a lot, you answer help me a lot.